# Create a dummy HTML Layout with pure CSS / HTML and display it as text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find a way to create an HTML layout and display it as text.
for example, i want to "paint" an area over the dummy html layout according to a selection.
I've made an example using images but my question is how to replace the images part with pure HTML / CSS?

just a side note, i'm working with a .Net environment (MVC)

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/sag1v/opo7jd9p/8/)

CSS:

```
img{
  display: none;
}
img:target {
    display: block;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <a href="#topHead">Top Head</a> |
  <a href="#bottomHead">Bottom Head</a> |
  <a href="#topBody">Top Bottom</a> |
  <a href="#bottomBody">Bottom Head</a>
  <div>
    <img id="topHead" src="https://s29.postimg.org/fjuguwv2f/htmlTopHead.png" alt="">
    <img id="bottomHead" src="https://s29.postimg.org/qtn6pv03r/htmlBottomHead.png" alt="">
    <img id="topBody" src="https://s29.postimg.org/vgt8rmngn/htmlTopBody.png" alt="">
    <img id="bottomBody" src="https://s29.postimg.org/q2ugk2xqf/htmlBottomBody.png" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html

This will replace the characters that are reserved in HTML and must be replaced with their corresponding HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

What about a syntax highlighter like [prism](http://prismjs.com/)? there are many others which can fit to your requirements.

If this doesn't help, your best option is coding the `html` file, and put inside each tag the scaped version, with your own styling.

Comment: isn't prism needs to be escaped anyway? i don't think you can write normal markup without escape chars